# Mouse click doesn't work in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

To get the final html-code of a website (in this example http://www.rtve.es/drmn/embed/video/3886778/) I need to emulate two mouse-clicks.

Following earlier questions and answers I built the following code in Python 2.7.13:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
driver.get('http://www.rtve.es/drmn/embed/video/3886778/')
time.sleep(3)
print driver.title                   # ---> correct title is shown
driver.save_screenshot('out.png')    # ---> correct screenshot is saved to disc

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='embed']/div/a/span/img").click() # ---> doesn't seem to work

el=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='embed']/div/a/span/img")
el.location
el.size         # ---> correct position and size of 'play'-icon is shown
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()   # ---> nothing happens

driver.save_screenshot('out2.png')   # ---> still the picture of the freeze frame
```

Well, this doesn't seem to work... I just have got to emulate the following:
- mouse-click at an arbitrary location
- wait until spot advertisement appears
- wait 3 seconds until "saltar promocion / skip advertisement" appears
- another mouse click at the "saltar promocion" element
- read in the final html

Any hints ?

Comment: It works using Firefox (after having installed gecko) instead of PhantomJS, but as you can't really minimize windows within Selenium I would still prefer a solution working with PhantomJS.

Comment: Using Firefox I can locate the 'play-icon' with
   el=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='embed']/div/a/span/img")
But I don't know how to locate the "saltar promocion"-icon, 
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".vast-skip-button enabled")
doesn't work. 

Furthermore I would prefer using the whole URL named http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/showEmbeddedCode.shtml?contentID=3886778&urlLocation=http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/cuentame-como-paso/cuentame-como-paso-t18-capitulo-313-amigo-americano/3886778/ instead of the abbreviation http://www.rtve.es/drmn/embed/video/3886778/.

Comment: After using the abbreviation-URL a couple of times I got a 503-error from the server, while the long URL keeps on working. But with the long URL I even can't find the 'play-icon'. Any ideas on this ?